# Create JSON value in SSM Parameter Store in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm

I need to create SSM parameter store in Cloudformation to store JSON

Here is my Template

```
Resources:
  WebServersSSM:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties: 
      AllowedPattern: String
      DataType: text
      Description: WebServers CloudWatch Agent Configuration
      Name: WebServersSSM
      Type: String
      Tier: Standard
      Value: |
        {
           ... My JSON File  
        }
```

I am facing error

```
Parameter value, cannot be validated against allowedPattern: String (Service: AmazonSSM; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ParameterPatternMismatchException; Request ID: a7c2f063-9e63-4b4c-981b-c9ad05e56166; Proxy: null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [AllowedPattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ssm-parameter.html#cfn-ssm-parameter-allowedpattern) is a regular expression to validate the pattern and not the expected type. Remove it and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes AllowedPattern must be remove of you want to store json in Value parameter